# How to set value or remove xmlns namespace in Xml

Tags: c#

I have a Xml file:

```
<ResourceDictionary 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" 
xmlns:inf="http://www.granfol.com/luna" >
  <Employees>
    <Employee Department="e" kk="TEST11111111">
      <Name>TestName11111</Name>
    </Employee>
  </Employees>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

and I want to set the xmlns to

```
xmlns=""
```

or

Directly Remove the xmlns default namespace.

### I have tried

```
XElement X = XElement.Load(@"FILEPATH");
IEnumerable<XAttribute> XI = X.Attributes();

foreach (XAttribute x in XI)
    Console.WriteLine(x);//Show all namespace in root

X.SetAttributeValue("xmlns","");  

foreach (XAttribute x in XI)
    Console.WriteLine(x);  //Here shows the namespace xmlns has change to ""

X.Save(@"FILEPATH"); //But when save File it throws Exception and failed
```

When save, it throws exception like  "The prefix cannot be redefined from to within the same start element tag"

I also tried to use

```
X.Attributes("xmlns").Remove();
```

to replace

```
X.SetAttributeValue("xmlns","");
```

above,

It doesn't throw exception when save,
but when I open the xml file, I see the "xmlns" doesn't disappear..

then I test and find

```
X.Attributes("xmlns")
```

doesn't contain xmlns, but contain "xmlns:x, xmlns:sys, xmlns:inf"

So is there some way to set value or remove xmlns namespace in Xml ?

I have thought a way is that to reproduce the whole xml file again,
but I'm not sure it's easy to do if the xml file is large.

I don't really know how to do it, but suppose it's not a good idea.

Comment: You should assign some prefix to `http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation` namespace, so that LINQ to XML can qualify elements with that prefix instead of using default namespace.

Comment: I'm not sure why but `using (XmlTextWriter d = new XmlTextWriter(@"FILEPATH", Encoding.UTF8)){d.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;X.WriteTo(d);}` instead of `X.Save(@"FILEPATH");` works.